# Windows Occasionally Fails To Move Folders

Tags: windows, file-transfer

I'm using Windows 7 and sometimes (but not always) when I try to move a folder to or from the desktop and sometimes it fails to move (or add) the folder the first time. Has anyone else experienced this?

Edit: This also applies to files.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe one of the files in that folder is open of being used by another application. Usually software like MS Office applications lock any open files.

Comment: I would think that, but even brand-new folders sometimes suffer from it.

Comment: Most probably its an app locking a file. Are these folders within the Dropbox folder (in case you are using Dropbox)? Even Dropbox (or other backup applications) can lock files.